# Comments in LaTeX break pandoc table

Tags: latex, pandoc

Pandoc is unable to convert LaTeX tables with an "% END" comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
   a & a & a \\
   a & a & a \\
   a & a & a \\
   % END 
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{example}
 \label{tab:example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The same example without the comment works fine.

Comment: @jam: Not really, since this question is about a conversion tool that takes LaTeX as input.

Comment: So, is your question how to get around this? Then the answer would be "Don't put such a comment at the end of the `tabular`".

Comment: This is a bug in pandoc.  I've already pushed a fix that will be in the next release.